# Mouse movement message being sent to another window is doing nothing

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

So basically I have a program that makes a transparent window which sits over another window. I am trying to make it so when you move your mouse in that transparent window, it will act like you moved your mouse in the window below it.

I have already tried looking at many other tutorials online, but none of them worked. On top of that I tried sending the message I got when I moved my mouse in that window to the window below it, but nothing happened (even though it detected my mouse moving). To make sure my code wasn't wrong, I also tried the same strategy by sending a message whenever the mouse if clicked, which worked perfectly.

Here is the code that I have tried but is not working:

```
case WM_MOVE:
{
    ShowCursor(false);
    SetForegroundWindow(otherWnd);
    SendMessage(otherWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    return 0;
}break;
```

otherWnd is the window below the transparent overlay, and this code is from a switch statement inside of WindowProc();

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If your window is really transparent then mouse events will go through to underlying windows by default.

Comment: If you have a [layered window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows), setting `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` lets mouse clicks through, even if the window is not fully transparent.

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). That, and [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SendInput function rather than trying to directly send keyboard and mouse messages.

Also, WM_MOVE is sent when a window itself is moved (I.E. title bar dragging) not when the mouse moves, the WM_MOUSEMOVE message indicates mouse movement.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to make it so when you move your mouse in that transparent window, it will act like you moved your mouse in the window below it.

If your window were *actually* transparent, the OS would handle that automatically for you.

Have your window procedure handle the `WM_(NC)HITTEST` message to return `HTTRANSPARENT` for any coordinates that should "pass through".

Comment: For layered windows, it's enough to set `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` to let mouse messages "pass through".